# Different User Objects Returning in Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API. However, I have a question/concern about the API returning different values for users depending on which endpoint is called.

Here is an example return value for the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/` endpoint.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "VALUE GOES HERE",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "Lname, Andrew",
    "givenName": "Andrew",
    "jobTitle": "MY TITLE",
    "mail": "andrew.lname@email.com",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": "123 Business Street",
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "Lname",
    "userPrincipalName": "andrew.lname@email.com"
}
```

This format remains the same when calling `/me/manager` and `/users/{ID}`, etc.

However, when we call `/me/people` we get a much larger and more complete user object.

```
{
    "id": "ID VALUE HERE",
    "displayName": "LName, Andrew",
    "givenName": "Andrew",
    "surname": "LName",
    "birthday": "",
    "personNotes": "",
    "isFavorite": false,
    "jobTitle": "MY TITLE",
    "companyName": "MY COMPANY NAME",
    "yomiCompany": "",
    "department": "MY DEPARTMENT",
    "officeLocation": "123 Business Street",
    "profession": "",
    "userPrincipalName": "andrew.lname@email.com",
    "imAddress": "sip:andrew.lname@email.com",
    "scoredEmailAddresses": [{
        "address": "andrew.lname@email.com",
        "relevanceScore": 285
    }],
    "phones": [{
        "type": "business",
        "number": "(555) 555-5555"
    }],
    "postalAddresses": [],
    "websites": [],
    "personType": {
        "class": "Person",
        "subclass": "OrganizationUser"
    }
}
```

First, does anyone know why there is a difference and more importantly, does anyone know how I can always retrieve the more robust user object?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things going on:

1. The [`person`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/person) and [`user`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user) objects are distinct resources with different properties. A `person` for example could represent a personal contact from Outlook, a contact from your organization GAL, or constructed from recent email or Skype communications. Contrast this with a `user` which always represents a User in your organizations Active Directory.
2. When you retrieve a `user` object without a `$select` parameter, Microsoft Graph will only return a subset of the `user` properties. This is done to save bandwidth by reducing the number of properties that get returned by default (you'd likely be shocked by how many calls get made to `/me` just to retrieve `DisplayName`). From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get):

   > Note: Getting a user returns a default set of properties only (`businessPhones`, `displayName`, `givenName`, `id`, `jobTitle`, `mail`, `mobilePhone`, `officeLocation`, `preferredLanguage`, `surname`, `userPrincipalName`). Use `$select` to get the other properties and relationships for the user object.

   In other words, when you call `/v1.0/me` Microsoft Graph is automatically appending `$select=businessPhones,displayName,givenName,id,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName` to your request. If you specify your own `$select` however it will use the one you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I've had several conversations with MSFT about this issue. At this time, they can't answer it. They recognize that the data models and data values are different between the /me user object and the /people user object but they aren't knowledgable as to how or why they are different. They are clearly different data models coming from different data sources but there are no diagrams as to where they get what data from. I was told that this is still just beta and that they will work to reconcile the two data models before they release but they were not sure when the release would be.